# How do I detect a change in value of a RadioNodeList?

Tags: javascript

With a form `my_form` with a set of radio buttons with `name=my_radio` I can get a [`RadioNodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/RadioNodeList) object with `my_form.elements.my_radio`. I can get the value of the currently selected button with that object's `value` property, and if I assign a string to the `value` property the selected option changes as appropriate.

I expected to be able to do `my_form.elements.my_radio.addEventListener('change', ...`, to listen for the value changing (via the user selecting a different option) but it has no such method.

How can I detect the value changing?

Is the only way to set up event listeners on each individual radio button object?

```js
var my_form = document.querySelector('#my_form');
var my_radio = my_form.elements.my_radio;

// This fails since RadioNodeList has no addEventListener function
/*
my_radio.addEventListener('change', function () {
console.log("Value changed; new value is " + my_radio.value);
});
*/

// The following works, but is there a better way, such as with a single event listener?
for (var i = 0, l = my_radio.length; i < l; i++) {
my_radio[i].addEventListener('change', function () {
 console.log("Value changed; new value is " + my_radio.value);
});
}
```

```html
<form id=my_form>
<div>
 <label>
  <input type=radio name=my_radio value=value_1>
  Value 1
 </label>
</div>
<div>
 <label>
  <input type=radio name=my_radio value=value_2>
  Value 2
 </label>
</div>
<div>
 <label>
  <input type=radio name=my_radio value=value_3>
  Value 3
 </label>
</div>
<div>
 <label>
  Some other field where I don't need to detect changes
  <input name=some_other_field>
 </label>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: That or set up an event listener on `my_form`; Nodes can get EventListeners, NodeLists cannot

Comment: A listener on `my_form` would have to check the changed element is one from the radio buttons in particular, right, since it'd also get called for any other element changing?

Comment: Please include example HTML (and JavaScript) in your question. In other words, please include a [mcve].  Doing so helps everyone be talking about the same thing. It also reduces the work that people have to do to answer your question. This makes it more likely that you A) get answers and B) the answers actually address *your* problem. Not to mention that a [mcve] is required for a debugging question, which this is, to be on-topic.

Comment: This isn't a debugging question. But I'll add some HTML and JS.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a "delegated event handler". You add a single handler to the radios' parent element (not necessarily the immediate parent), then use `event.target` to see which element was actually clicked - if it wasn't one of the radios then do nothing.

Comment: Sure, that's near enough what @Hamms suggested in his or her comment above. This would definitely be a solution with a single event listener, but it then needs extra logic, as you say, to determine if we care about this particular event or not. I was mainly hoping there was something in the RadioNodeList API I was missing, since the way I wanted to solve the problem (my commented-out code) would be exactly the same whether it was a RadioNodeList or a type=select element, which seems nice to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your markup, wrap just the radio buttons in a [`fieldset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset). Then attach the event-listener to that instead of the form, so it won't fire for changes to other `<input>` fields.

Here is the modified code:

```js
var my_form = document.querySelector('#my_form');
var my_radio = my_form.elements.my_radio;
var my_radio_group = document.querySelector('#my_radio_group');

// Attach the eventListener to the fieldset instead of the form
my_radio_group.addEventListener('change', function() {
  // You actually don't even need the other global variables; this also works:
  // let my_radio = this.form.elements.my_radio);
  console.log("Value changed; new value is " + my_radio.value);  
});
```

```css
/* If you don't want any border around the radio group */
#my_radio_group {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="my_form">
  <fieldset id="my_radio_group">
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="value_1">
        Value 1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="value_2">
        Value 2
      </label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="my_radio" value="value_3">
        Value 3
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <div>
    <label>
      Some other field where I don't need to detect changes
      <input name="some_other_field">
     </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

### Why OP's first approach fails

A `RadioNodeList`, being a kind of `NodeList`, is a collection of Nodes (radio elements in this case). As such, it is much like a JS Array (you can do `my_radio[i]`). In JS, Events can be received only by objects that inherit the `EventTarget` interface, like Nodes and HTML Elements, and not by collections like arrays and `NodeLists`.

To attach a single event handler for multiple elements, you have to attach it to a close parent and use [Event Delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture). Which is what I did in my solution, using the `<fieldset>` element. Any wrapper element e.g. `<div>` would have sufficed; only that the `<fieldset>` is semantically more accurate here.

Comment: That does the job. Thank you. It still seems a shame to me that I can't use some event of RadioNodeList for this!

Comment: Well, that's because RadioNodeList is an Array-like object, and hence you can't have JS events on it. I have edited my answer to add a bit of explanation. Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
my_form.addEventListener('change', function () {
console.log("Value changed; new value is " + my_radio.value);
});
```

Comment: This would fire when any other input in the form changes, such as `some_other_field` in my example.

Answer (score 0):

document.formName.radioButtons[thisOne].click()

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and add explanation to your post.